# Flash presentation SWF

Tags: presentation, flash

I have a homework to make a presentation about biology. So, I wanna make this presentation openable on a movie player or something like that, and I wanna add some animations which can be clickable to play or pause on that presentation. [See an example](https://sites.google.com/site/hendragunawanfiles/home/my-friends-download-files/SEL%20HEWAN.swf?attredirects=1).

What software can do that things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a free option I would suggest [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/).

It is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Available for Windows, Linux & OS-X
- Powerful
- Comes as part of a complete integrated office suite.
- Can save presentations as a number of formats including:

  - PDF Presentation
  - Flash SWF
  - HTML Presentation *(Recommended as no software to install on viewers machine)*
- Also comes with presentation tools allowing you to practice timings, see prompts not shown to the audience, etc.

Comment: I am using Windows, u sure Libreffice can add animations which can playable on that presentation? Thx before

Comment: Yes I am sure + plus as it is free it will cost you next to nothing to try.

Comment: How to save as .swf , i didn't see any option to save as .swf? And did you know how to make a option like https://i.imgsafe.org/43f9d4171b.png

Comment: On my installation it is File->Export to save as swf IIRC.